# How to check users device (Android, iOS or PC)?

Tags: javascript, web, frontend, detection, mobile-website

I want to create a site on which there will be registration form and links to applications in App Store and Google Play. If a person comes in from the phone, he sees the usual registration / login form. If a person comes in with android, he sees a link to Google Play.

Sorry if poorly explained. It should be something like this site https://iq-option.bid/ (the first example I found). For mobile users, it shows a link to the store for installing the application, and from the computer - the usual registration form.

Comment: This might help: [Browser detection using the user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Answer (score 0):

although your question was poorly worded, I understand what you need.

And I rectify why your question was asked incorrectly, due to lack of knowledge in the field. I respect and admire that you came to find a solution.

I'll give you my long-standing opinion on work and website development ... Ok ...

What are you describing ...
For each device, it will enter a page ...
Well, it can even be done ...
But it generates a lot of time and a lot of complexity, for something that could be easier ... A lot for those who are doing it ... So easy for the final process.

After all, whoever enters the iPhone, he searches for the app store, whoever enters Android looks for the Play Store and whoever enters the PC, looks for a Chrome extension or some relevant information.

Well, what I advise is to focus on whether what you are asking for is really necessary. Because I see that it is simply a complement that may be automatically unnecessary. Because that thought is an obvious thing for the end user.

Now, in which programming language are you creating this site?
Is it a CMS? As this function you want can be easy to implement with a plug-in, for example ...

I hope I helped and we will continue the feddback until the solution ... Ok ..

Up until

Comment: Now, for you to only have a report from which device the customer is accessing for data analysis, you can use Google Analytics, just implement the code on your website. OK.

Anything, please ask

i would love to help you with yours. new project!